# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to use `enum` as a reference to another `enum`. Even though it works, TS gives an error.

```
enum One {
    some = 'some text here',
    other = 'other stuff here'
}

enum Two {
    thing = 'some',
    whatever = 'other'
}

Object.keys(Two).forEach(k =>  console.log(One[Two[k]]))
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Console:
// some text here
// other stuff here
```

Gives the follow error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof One'.(7053)
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Two'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Two'.(7053)

Comment: You need `(Object.keys(Two) as Array<keyof typeof Two>)`.